# Set the PORT NodeJs Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, server, axios, mern

I created an app on Heroku, and pulled my GitHub repository.

My app displays well, but the port of my backend change every time I have a new build.

Here is how I tried to set it :

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'localhost',
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))
app.use(cookieParser())

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'))
}

// routes
app.use('/api', routes)

//server 
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`)
})
```

Even if I set only `5000`, I have a port like `Listening on port 54435`

Any idea how to have a fixed port for my backend ?

I need it because my axios request with my frontend (React) need the port (obviously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deploying your app to heroku, heroku gives you a link e.g. `mynewapp.heroku.com`.

Now in your axios request of frontend (React), replace all the

`http://localhost:5000` with `mynewapp.heroku.com`.

Here no need to specify any port number.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to hardcode the port on Heroku: apps must bind to the `PORT` provided at runtime.

Each app can be deployed in a Web Dyno so you can invoke the backend using the `herokuapp.com` URL.